# GitHub Workflows - Pull request, get branch name

Tags: git, github, github-actions, branch

I have a GitHub workflow that is triggered when in a Pull Request a comment is made

```
if: ${{ github.event.comment.body == '/some_comment'}} && ${{ github.event.issue.pull_request }}
```

When the workflow is being executed, the checkout action clones the master branch and not the actual branch in the PR.

```
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

I tried all sorts of outputs but without luck :( For the examples below all echos are null.

```
    - run: "echo ${{github.event.pull_request.head.sha}}"
    - run: "echo ${{github.event.workflow_run.head.sha}}"
    - run: "echo ${{github.event.workflow_run.base.sha}}"
    - run: "echo ${{github.event.pull_request.base.sha}}"
```

Do any of you know how to check out the source branch in the PR in the Github Action?

Thank you

Comment: What's your exact trigger in `on:`?

Answer (score 1):

try with `github.ref`. [From the doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts):

```
github.ref  The fully-formed ref of the branch or tag that triggered the workflow run. For workflows triggered by push, this is the branch or tag ref that was pushed. 
For workflows triggered by pull_request, this is the pull request merge branch. 
For workflows triggered by release, this is the release tag created. For other triggers, this is the branch or tag ref that triggered the workflow run. 
This is only set if a branch or tag is available for the event type. 
The ref given is fully-formed, meaning that for branches the format is refs/heads/<branch_name>, for pull requests it is refs/pull/<pr_number>/merge, and for tags it is refs/tags/<tag_name>. 
For example, refs/heads/feature-branch-1.
```

You could also use some existing GitHub Action, like [Branch Names](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/branch-names)

```
    steps:
      - name: Get branch name
        id: branch-name
        uses: tj-actions/branch-names@v6
        
      - name: Running on the default branch.
        if: steps.branch-name.outputs.is_default == 'true'
        run: |
          echo "Running on default: ${{ steps.branch-name.outputs.current_branch }}"
        # Outputs: "Running on default: main".
      
      - name: Running on a pull request branch.
        if: steps.branch-name.outputs.is_default == 'false'
        run: |
          echo "Running on pr: ${{ steps.branch-name.outputs.current_branch }}"
        # Outputs: "Running on pr: feature/test".
```

Comment: How can you tell the event that triggered the first workflow (i.e. a push or pull request)? This would normally be achieved with `github.event_name`, but this field resolves to `workflow_run` in the second workflow.